# Echoing whole website's html with file_get_contents

Tags: php

I'm trying to echo a whole website's code, and read it as text. The code below does get me the code of the website.

```
echo file_get_contents('http://google.com');
```

But if I try to read it as a text by using code below, it says `string(0) ""`

```
var_dump(htmlentities(file_get_contents('http://google.com')));
var_dump(htmlspecialchars(file_get_contents('http://google.com')));
```

How can I make it echo the whole code?

Comment: specify proper encoding for html...() and do not use google.com

Comment: why htmlentities() or htmlspecialchars() is not proper? And why don't use google.com? I need this to work this on anything or atleast know why not to use it.

Comment: seems this is something related to the server environment and location. as i  tested it locally and on some online ide's and sometimes i get the full HTML and sometimes it's empty, if there is a local google site of your server location try that google site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the content returned by `www.google.com` uses a different encoding than `htmlspecialchars()` expects. For me, the page at `www.google.com` looks like it is encoded as `ISO-8859-2` and `htmlspecialchars()` expects to process `UTF-8`.

In consequence, both [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) and [`htmlentities()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) fail to interpret the input string properly and they give up and return empty strings when they reach byte sequences that are not valid `UTF-8` encoding.

There are several ways to fix this. The easiest one is to pass `ENT_IGNORE` or `ENT_SUBSTITUTE` as the second argument to `htmlspecialchars()` but it doesn't address the cause of the problem, it just hides it.

Another way is to pass the charset of the page content as the third argument to `htmlspecialchars()` (if you know it). Unfortunately, the list of charsets supported by `htmlspecialchars()` is quite limited and yours might not be in the list.

But, **if you know** the charset of the page you can use [`mb_convert_encoding()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php) to encode the string as `UTF-8` and then `htmlspecialchars()` works like a charm!

However, if you don't know the charset in advance then the correct solution is to get the page using [`curl`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) with options `CURLOPT_HEADER`, `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` (and possibly `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION`). This way you can get both the page content and the headers of the response and, by analyzing the headers you can find out the correct charset used by the server to encode the response. For me, the response contains the header:

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-2
```

and this confirms my previous supposition.

Or you can use a library that wraps `curl` and helps you get the content and the meta-data returned in the headers easier.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Love you.

Answer (score 0):

Your example seems to work in my tests, not sure why you're getting `string(0) ""` even though you can `echo` the website's content. Try this:

```
<?php

$site = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com');

$htmlentities = htmlentities($site);

$htmlspecialchars = htmlspecialchars($site);

echo $htmlentities;
echo $htmlspecialchars;

?>
```

Both `$htmlentities` and `$htmlspecialchars` output pure HTML on my side, use whichever you like, note that I've stored the result from `file_get_contents()` in a variable to prevent PHP from fetching the page 2 times in your tests.

Comment: It does work with www.example.com, but for example www.google.com doesn't. It seems the code of website itself has to do something with this, but can't find the solution at php.net. Anyway thanks for showing me this, know I can stop hitting wall over something that simple.

Comment: I have actually tried it on google.com before posting the answer and it works. Just used example.com for documentation purposes... I guess the issue has something to do with your development environment.